# Mysql take a value in a column divide by the average of the entire column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery

How can I take for each value in a column, the value divided by the average of that column and have it return me a value in a new column?

Here is my table:

```
A  B   C
_  _   _
1  4   #((1/2)+(1/8))/2 # this is data i hope to get in col C
2  9   #((2/2)+(9/8))/2
3  11  #((3/2)+(11/8))/2
```

The formula i want in column c is :( A/AVG(A)+B/AVG(B) )/2

Here is my MYSQL query:

```
update table f
set f.C=(((f.A)/(SELECT AVG(f.A)))+((f.B)/(SELECT AVG(f.B))))/2;
```

I ended up only getting 1 in all the rows for col C.

Thanks

Comment: your example suggests you need to SELECT SUM(F.A) ... and not AVG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one statement by using an `update` with a `join`:

```
update table f cross join
       (select sum(a) as suma, sum(b) as sumb
        from table f
       ) var
  set f.C = (f.A/var.suma + f.B/var.sumb) / 2;
```

Comment: If i actually needed the average of the coumn, and not the sum (as seen in my edits) do i just change the sum() to avg()?

Comment: @jenn . . . Yes.  I went by the numerical example rather than the specific code.

Answer (score 0):

what you expect is this:

```
( A/SUM(A)+B/SUM(B) )/2
```

And not

```
( A/AVG(A)+B/AVG(B) )/2
```

Therefore, do:

```
update table f
set f.C=(((f.A)/(SELECT SUM(f.A)))+((f.B)/(SELECT SUM(f.B))))/2;
```

Comment: hm this did not work. I still got 1 for all the values in col C.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a variable to set the averages and then run the current query

```
SET @avgA = (SELECT AVG(f.A) FROM f);
SET @avgB = (SELECT AVG(f.B) FROM f);

update table f
  set f.C=(((f.A)/(@avgA))+((f.B)/(@avgB)))/2;
```